# How convert multi value row to columns using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

What functions do I use to convert this Dataframe:

```
id name genre

1 Fiml1 action, comedy
2 Fiml2 animation
3 Fiml3 comedy
4 Fiml4 action, animation
5 Fiml5 action
6 Fiml6 animation, comedy
```

To:

```
id name action animation comedy

1  Fiml1   1       0       1
2  Fiml2   0       1       0
3  Fiml3   0       0       1
4  Fiml4   1       1       0
5  Fiml5   1       0       0
6  Fiml6   0       1       1
```

This dataframe is to be used in vector space model, answer or any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`Series.str.dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with `', '` as seperator:

```
df = pd.concat([
    df[['id', 'name']], df['genre'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ')
], axis=1)
```

```
   id   name  action  animation  comedy
0   1  Fiml1       1          0       1
1   2  Fiml2       0          1       0
2   3  Fiml3       0          0       1
3   4  Fiml4       1          1       0
4   5  Fiml5       1          0       0
5   6  Fiml6       0          1       1
```